# background color for certain items(rows) in QFileSystemModel QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

How do i set a custom background color for certain rows in a QFileSystemModel applied on a QTreeView?

Comment: could you place a small snap shot so that we can suggest some ideas.

Comment: The qt example from http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/itemviews-dirview-main-cpp.html should be enough. For eg. i want to set a custom background for rows with directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setData method and Qt::BackgroundColorRole to achieve that. This should work.

Comment: Above answer doesn't work.
QFileSystemModel rejects all calls to setData that is not of the role "Qt::EditRole".